# Can I move the tabs into the title bar in Internet Explorer 9?

Tags: tabs, gui, internet-explorer-9

Internet Explorer 9 has a nice minimalistic arrangement of URL box and tabs.

However, when the window is maximized, there is a ugly title bar line on top of the browser:

[image: IE empty line on top]

For comparison (Chrome):

[image: Chrome tabs on top]

Is there an option to remove the title bar, or put tabs at top of the screen?

Comment: you could press F11... to go full screen

Comment: You could use Chrome which does this natively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Natively in the application with out a plug-in. no

Answer (score 0):

Many applications have this problem due to the way GUIs, in general, are designed.  If you enter Full Screen mode (you can press the F11 key to toggle this), the tabs and title bar should disappear automatically (and re-appear when you move the mouse to the extreme top of the screen).